# Maximising area of book cover

Tags: geometry

I've bee posed this puzzle of a book cover conundrum and am struggling to solve it, how should I go about tackling this problem?

> I have two books of equal dimensions. The ratio of the short side of
>   the book to the long side is $1:\sqrt{2}$. The two books are stacked such
>   that the top book's cover completely covers the bottom book's cover
>   when viewed top down. The top book is then rotated slowly. At what
>   angle will the maximum area of the bottom book be visible?

Comment: Around which point is the top book rotated? Also, could you edit your post to show some of your thoughts?

Comment: either the center or a vertex. if it were a vertex the problem would be trivial, so it's probably the center.

Comment: Try finding the area as a function of the angle.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to assume at 90 degrees, since the function is monotonic. It will not be surprising to find it to be a kind of sine wave. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assume the top book rotates around the center of both books and let $\theta$ be angle between their diagonal lines (shown in the left figure). Then, it can be shown that the sum of the four exposed triangle areas of the bottom book as a function of the rotating angle $\theta$ is

$$A (\theta)= \frac{d^2}2\cdot \frac{\tan\theta(1-\frac{2\sqrt2}3\sin\theta)}{1+\cos\theta}$$

where $d$ is the diagonal length of the books.

Furthermore, it can be shown the $A'(\theta)> 0$, i.e. an increasing function of $\theta$. So, the maximum exposure is in the limit where the corners of the two books coincide, or

$$A(\theta)\le A(\theta_m)=\frac{d^2}{6\sqrt2},\>\>\>\>\>\theta_m = 2\cot\sqrt2$$

as shown in the middle figure.

However, the exposed area still increases as the rotation passes the limit angle $\theta_m$ and become trapezoids. It can be shown that the overlapping area (the parallelogram in grey) is the smallest when the two books are perpendicular to each other, shown by the right figure. Thus, the exposed area is the largest at the 90-degree rotation.